# Couldn't install excel4node in VSCode

Tags: javascript

npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "jsdom 2": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

I am facing this error while trying to install excel4node in VSCode

Comment: Try looking for any `package.json` file with the name "jsdom 2". Then change it to "jsdom2". I assume it will be a user-created file.

Comment: Thankyou ,helped me resolved the error!!!